# Running a personal macro book from PyWin32

Tags: python, vba, excel

```
 xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

 if os.path.isfile(path_excel):

        workbook1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(path_excel)

x1.Workbooks.Add("C:\\Users\\ms35814\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\PERSONAL.XLSB")

xl.Application.Run('PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt')
xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
del xl
```

The above given is the script I am using to call my personal macro book from python, but it gives an error

> NameError: name 'x1' is not defined

I had already installed *PyWin32* and imported both `win32com.client` and `os`.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a typo. You're using XL everywhere but your Workbooks.Add, there you have X1

Comment: yeah ! sorry that was terrible, but I have another issue after correcting that typo:  ', u"Sorry, we couldn't find C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\PERSONAL.XLSB. Is it
 possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), the error is coming for x1.Application.Run('PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt') . I don't know why its searching for the above path because the path for personal.xlsb is mentioned in script

Comment: try to specify the full file path in your Application.Run. Maybe it searches in Documents by default if you don't specify the file path.

Comment: run_mac = path_excel + 'PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt'
x1.Application.Run(run_mac)  .I tried this but it shows this error now: we couldn't find D:\\CWT files\\CDL\\CDLfile_list.xlsxPERSONAL.XLSB.

Comment: looks like you're missing a backslash before the filename, try `run_mac = path_excel + '\\PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt'`

Comment: And your path_excel already contains a filename and you're adding another one to it, decide which one you want to use. Either CDLfile_list.xlsx or PERSONAL.XLSB

Comment: I am actually creating CDLfile_list.xlsx now in python using xlsxwriter after making of document I want to run personal.xlsb macro on the CD_file_list . I am able to see personal.xlsb!iss_cwt10 macro in CDL_file_list after creation and also able to run that macro, but I am facing difficulty in running personal.xlsb on CDL_file via python script

Comment: I got the solution! We have to open both workbooks (personal.xlsb as well as the file on which we have to run macro)and need to run x1.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt"). Anyway thanks gizlmo for your support.   P.S: I don't know whether I should put it in answer. Anyway this worked for me.

Comment: Yes, put an answer and mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution! We have to open both workbooks (personal.xlsb as well as the file on which we have to run macro)and need to run x1.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!iss10_cwt").